# Passing Array from Javascript to C#

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays

I have a .js script that contain an array:

The output of the js is like:

```
var foo=
[
    {
        "bar1":"value1",
        "bar2":"value2"
        // And so on...            
    }
]
```

I have no access to the js source, so i cannot output as JSON and Deserialize.

I can only get this as a String using `WebClient`, but how i can parse it and create an Array/Dictionary and work on it inside C#?

Comment: I believe you can do this : var foo = new `JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<YourModelHere>>(YourString);`

Comment: What is the string you get with `WebClient`? Because you ask how to parse it but don't show it.

Comment: @I4V The string is the output of the js. Exactly like i wrote.

Comment: @WiS3 does the _string_ start with "var foo = " or is that how it's set in the JavaScript?

Comment: @DStanley The string starts with "var foo...", it is plain text, like reading a .txt.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider calling `WebClient.DownloadString` . Then Parse using `JSON.Net` or whatever

As per the example provided over there

```
string json = @"{
  ""Name"": ""Apple"",
  ""Expiry"": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
  ""Price"": 3.99,
  ""Sizes"": [
    ""Small"",
    ""Medium"",
    ""Large""
  ]

}";
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
string name = (string)o["Name"];
// Apple
JArray sizes = (JArray)o["Sizes"];
string smallest = (string)sizes[0];

// Small
```

Answer (score 0):

`var foo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<YourModelHere>>(YourString);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to deserialize that string:

```
string str=
@"var foo = 
  [
    {
        ""bar1"":""value1"",
        ""bar2"":""value2""

    }
]";

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var o = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>[]>(str.Substring(str.IndexOf('[')));
```

Result:

```
Dictionary<String,String> (2 items)   

Key    Value 
------ --------
bar1   value1 
bar2   value2
```

Comment: D Stanley, I expected this answer:) But javascript can not be parsed with json parsers. Suppose a line like `"bar3": Math.max(a,b)`

Comment: @I4V The example provided does not have embedded code - I have tested my answer with the provided example and it works.

Comment: D Stanley, I know it works, I just say,  OP is trying to do something wrong and your answer works for the posted example (A very primiteve string op. to be able to pass it to json parser). What do you think for this? `I have a .js script that contain an array:`. Do you expect your answer would work for every `js` that contains an array?